# Can I set Tomcat SSL port other then 443 or 8443

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have Plesk on my server that is using both ports as:

```
#netstat -lnp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5513/sw-cp-server:  
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      32660/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      5513/sw-cp-server:  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     110443   31339/dovecot        /var/run/dovecot/stats
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html (First Google hit, incidentally)